# Async API request axios and redux freeze app in react

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

I'm trying to make an asynchronous request of an API.
In the meantime I am waiting for a response from it, starts preloader but at a certain moment it freeze. The request, I do it with axios and redux. What am I doing wrong?

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getPosts = () => {
    return async (dispatch:any) => {
    try {

            dispatch({ type: 'GET_POSTS_BEGIN' });
            const resp = await axios.get('MYAPI')
            .then((resp) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'GET_POSTS_SUCCESS',
                    posts: resp.data
                })
            })


        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
}
```